# Css not working correctly on ie11 web server

Tags: html, css, webserver

I have a problem with my website after uploading it on the webserver, basically the background changes picture every 6 seconds, and I've accomplish that using css. Everything works fine when I open the html file from my hard disk, in chrome and ie 11. When using the web server, everything still works fine on chrome, but on internet explorer 11 won't work.  Can someone help me?

Comment: Please post the link.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: The website is on intranet, so I'll post the Jsfiddle link:  https://jsfiddle.net/oyj5hdw9/

Comment: @Werokk Did you try changing the width and height from the image to auto? And did you check your console for errors like img src not found?

Comment: If I change the width and height to auto, it won't display on full screen. There are no errors, on chrome works perfectly.